# What's the name of this CRT monitor?

Tags: crt-monitor

What's the name of this output retro gaming monitor device? 
The following is a still from the Netflix production of 'Bandersnatch', a 2018 interactive movie, set in Britain, mostly in the year 1984.

[image]

The CRT Monitor has buttons which read 1 to 8, RGB and Video. A microcomputer is connected (not shown) to which a joystick is connected.

Comment: What is that? Game, or monitor, or what?

Comment: How old are you? (That's not a rhetorical question, I'm genuinely curious. What you have there is a bog-standard CRT television, probably from the first half of the 80s (it does have composite and RGB input, but only 8 channels and probably no remote.).

Comment: It might be useful if you could add some additional information, like where the picture is taken from and in what context.

Comment: 2 years ago I went to a telcom shop for a sim card and there was this 60+ year old gentleman trying to buy a land line telephone. When he was checking the item he asked why this phone doesn't have a power connector. People do forget how old times works.

Comment: @user3528438 and in the time period we’re considering here, land-line phones didn’t even have power cords ;-)

Comment: I love the fact that the question has been answered by tagging it.

Comment: @MarkWilliams I thought "crt monitor" is suitable tag for my question.

Comment: @MichaelGraf I am over 25.

Comment: Thank you for a great question @TommyCraig. As you added the Tag, I have updated your question to make it clearer, and added a bit of context. I hope it is still in line with your intentions.

Comment: @MarkWilliams an unfortunate side-effect of your edit is that it means I need to adjust my answer to match (and a lot of the investigation involved in my answer gets absorbed into the question — granted, the information could probably have been there right from the start...).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to reflect the original knowledge and intention of our new user. They tagged the question so they knew this was a CRT, even if they didn't make this clear. Please leave your answer as is, it is very good.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It’s a regular 80s-era TV set, specifically a [Ferguson MC01](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_AzT5pruwnbg/SyAUXUB2C4I/AAAAAAAAISY/VqNb47oVRJw/s1600-h/1986.jpg) (from a 1986 Argos catalogue, see [this article](https://80sactual.blogspot.com/2008/09/some-1980s-television-sets.html)): the buttons are volume, brightness, contrast, colour, and channel selection buttons. This particular model was designed to be computer-friendly, with RGB support and automatic switching. Ferguson also produced an add-on for 48K ZX Spectrum computers, [the MA20](https://www.worldofspectrum.org/infoseekid.cgi?id=1000168), which provided RGB output for use with such TVs (also mentioned in [CRASH](http://www.crashonline.org.uk/25/technews.htm)).

[image: Argos catalogue showing the Ferguson MC-01]

The joystick wouldn’t be connected to the TV itself, but to a computer connected to the TV.

Your photo is a screengrab from [*Black Mirror: Bandersnatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror%3A_Bandersnatch), and the game shown is the titular *Bandersnatch*, one of the fictional [Tuckersoft games](https://www.tuckersoft.net/ealing20541/history/). This also explains the UK spelling on the TV, which can be seen in more detail [in this featurette](https://youtu.be/VNw9DAwp2Kk?t=116). The computer would be a [ZX Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum).

(Thanks to [Tommy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4147/tommy) and [Michael Graf](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/10666/michael-graf) for contributing to this spelunking adventure.)

Comment: It not only supports RGB, but Ferguson sold a corresponding hardware add-on for the 48kb ZX Spectrum that added RGB output, the MA20. This TV was explicitly pushed as also being a monitor for home computers, with trade-specific advertising. Minor mention in Crash magainze: http://www.crashonline.org.uk/25/technews.htm (see the fourth news item); pictures of the RGB adaptor: https://k1.spdns.de/Vintage/Sinclair/82/Peripherals/RGB%20TV:monitor%20interfaces/MA20%20RGB%20Interface%20(Ferguson)/

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: The (fictional) Tuckersoft fansite you linked to confirms it's in fact Bandersnatch: https://www.tuckersoft.net/ealing20541/bandersnatch/
And finding that TV in the Argos catalog is some impressive detective work!

Comment: @Michael thanks ;-). The Bandersnatch link doesn’t work for me, it immediately redirects to the history page, so I’ll take your word for it.

Comment: @StephenKitt condensing the nonsense, here's the Bandersnatch screenshot, to evidence Michael's observation: https://www.tuckersoft.net/ealing20541/img/thumb-bandersnatch2.gif . So he and you are definitely right.

Comment: @Tommy Awesome. Another piece of Brit IT history I never knew I was missing. Now I need to get both, TV and Sinclair connector box :))

Comment: In 1986, the cost of that TV was around 1 week's salary for a qualified UK teacher, now, you can get a 19 inch LED TV with a VGA input for £99.99 at Argos, which is around 1 day's salary.

Comment: In case anyone wants to have the exact TV in question, this specific Ferguson TV can be hired from the same people who supplied it for the Bandersnatch filming: https://www.tvfilmprops.co.uk/det/2831/Black-Mirror-Bandersnatch/ and https://www.tvfilmprops.co.uk/det/2121/Ferguson-TX-3MC01D0-Television/